# JarHell in legacy code using java 9 modules in maven

Tags: java, maven, java-module

I'm trying to create a spring boot application with the latest version 3.0.4.
I need to use a REST API for which I found a heavy client that relies on the same dependencies as spring but in an older version (com.jaspersoft:jrs-rest-java-client:8.1.0).

This lead to a JarHell that I tried to fix with Java 9 modules. Therefore I split my application in two modules, the first one being an API over `jrs-rest-java-client`, the second module being the full spring-boot application.

As `jrs-rest-java-client` is not "module ready" I need to declare it as an automatic module.
Yet I can't run any basic application on it (even without spring) as it keeps complaining that some code deep inside the `jrs-rest-java-client` jar stack is requesting access to some other module. The same code runs without any problem if I disable java 9 module.

Don't automatic modules imply `transitive` ?

How to deal with legacy code ? Shall we explicitly require the whole jar stack ?

Sample error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module com.sun.xml.txw2 not found, required by com.sun.xml.bind
```

Comment: "This lead to a JarHell that I tried to fix with Java 9 modules." - This does not sound like a good idea. Better use a different REST client, or try to use it the REST client with the newer dependencies.

Comment: @JFabianMeier, I'm fully aware of that : from what I know the API is only described in the documentation and is "a little bit" complicated. Hence I decided to stick with the official client, betting on the fact that it would be easier to use modules. I still hope I'm one tuto away from mastering Java modules. Finger crossed !

Comment: Until now I have not seen a good use case for modules.

Comment: Find another client or adopt your code to use the same dependency.

Comment: When you use Maven, there should be only one dependeny of any kind on the classpath. You can also exclude transitive dependencies. Using modules won't save you from this because it still wouldn't allow having the same module, only with different versions, twice on the module path, unless you use custom layers.